Step$-N$ Euler approximation of controlled differential equation
My goal is to understand higher-order Euler schemes for differential equations of the type $$d y_t = V(y_t) dx_t := \sum_{i=1}^d V_i(y_t) dx_t,$$
where $x:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^e$ are paths, and $V \in C(\mathbb{R}^e, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^e))$ is some continuous vector field, which can be equivalently interpreted as a collection $(V_1,...,V_d)$ of vector fields $V_i : \mathbb{R}^e \to \mathbb{R}^e$. As usual, the equation above is interpreted in terms of its integral form:
$$y_t = y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t V_i(y_r) dx_r.$$
Of course one needs to give proper meaning to the integral above. To that end, simply assume $x$ to be of bounded variation. I am mostly interested in the heuristics at the beginning of Chapter 7 of the book Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths, by P. K. Friz & N. B. Victoir.
The authors write: "Let $I$ denote the identity function on $\mathbb{R}^e$ and recall the identification of a vector field $W = (W^1,...,W^e)^T:\mathbb{R}^e \to \mathbb{R}^e$ with the first-order differential operator $\sum_{k=1}^e W^k(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}$. Granted suﬃcient regularity of $V$, a simple Taylor expansion suggests, at least for $0 < t−s << 1$, a step$-N$ approximation of the form:"
$$y_t \approx y_s + \sum_{i=1}^d V_i(y_s) (x_t^i - x_s^i) + ...+ \sum_{i_1,...,i_N \in \{1,...,d\}} V_{i_1} \cdots V_{i_N} I(y_s) \int_s^t \int_s^{u_N} \cdots \int_s^{u_2} dx_{u_1}^{i_1} ... dx_{u_N}^{i_N}.$$
How exactly are we arriving at this expression? I can understand a level-$1$ approximation but for higher levels I don't get an identical expression to theirs. To elaborate, granted enough regularity to $V$, we have that
$$V(y_r) \approx V(y_s) + DV(y_s)(y_r - y_s),$$
and substituting this in the differential equation we get
\begin{align*}
y_t \approx& y_s + \int_s^t V(y_s) d x_r + \int_s^t DV(y_s)(y_r - y_s) \otimes dx_r \\
=& y_s + \sum_{i=1}^d V_i(y_s) (x_t^i - x_s^i) + DV(y_s) \int_s^t (y_r - y_s) \otimes dx_r.
\end{align*}
We can further approximate the integrand of the last term and obtain:
\begin{align*}
y_t \approx y_s + \sum_{i=1}^d V_i(y_s) (x_t^i - x_s^i) + DV(y_s) \int_s^t \int_s^r V(y_u)dx_udx_r \otimes dx_r.
\end{align*}
But still, it's not quite what the authors end up with. Could someone shed some light on this? How do we get that step$-N$ approximation?

Let me give you the derivation for the step-2 approximation. You can then just repeat the computation to arrive at the expression for the step-N approximation given by the authors.
By setting $f:= V_i I$ in Exercise 3.17, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
y_t &= y_s + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_s^t (V_i I)(y_r) dx_r^i \\
&= y_s + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_s^t (V_i I) (y_r) - (V_i I) (y_s) dx_r^i + \sum_{i=1}^d (V_i I) (y_s)x_{s,t}^i \\
&\overset{3.17}{=} y_s + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_s^t \int_s^r \sum_{j=1}^d(V_j V_i I )(y_u) dx_u^j dx_r^i + \sum_{i=1}^d (V_i I) (y_s)x_{s,t}^i \\
&\overset{0< t-s \ll 1}{\approx} y_s + \sum_{i=1}^d (V_i I) (y_s) x_{s,t}^i + \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^d (V_j V_i I) (y_s) \int_s^t \int_s^r dx_u^j dx_r^i.
\end{align}
$$
Here, we use the notation $x_{s,t} = x_t - x_s$ as in the book.

Thanks for the answer @cripper. What you write is clear, however I still struggle with this identification of $V$ with a 1st order differential operator... Under the conditions of Ex 3.17 we have that $\int_0^T (Vf)(y_s) dx_s = \sum_{i=1}^d\sum_{k=1}^e \int_0^T V_i^k \partial_k f(y_s) dx_s^i$.  How is this expression equal to $f(y_T) - f(y_0)$? Could you elaborate on this?

The expression they write comes from a repeated application of the change-of-variables rule for ODEs driven by finite variation signals. You can consult the proof of Proposition 10.3 from the very same book for further explanation. (No knowledge of chapters 7,8,9 is required to understand the statement or the proof of the latter.)

You should probably make your answer a bit more concrete.

Hey @LeonW thanks for having a look. Yeah that part I got already. Exercise 3.17, right? Also, what you say is exactly what the authors mention on the proof of Prop 10.3 (without further elaboration). I suppose this is something straightforward if one is used to these "differential operator identifications". I'm not and that's the part I was asking help with. My question in other words: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5002357/vector-fields-as-differential-operators-acting-on-other-vector-fields
