Vector fields as differential operators acting on other vector fields
I'm having some trouble understanding how vector fields act on other vector fields, as I'm not extremely familiar with differential geometry. From what I read, I believe it's standard practise in the subject to identify a vector field $W: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with the first-order differential operator
$$\sum_{k=1}^n W^k(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}. \quad (\dagger)$$
Roughly speaking, this seems to make sense to me as tangent vectors are interpreted as derivations, and derivations are in one-to-one correspondence with directional derivatives. Let me know if I'm thinking straight.
Now, let $V: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a matrix-valued vector field. More conveniently, we may look at $V$ as a collection of "column vector fields" $(V_1,...,V_d)$, where $V_i$ goes from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $i \in \{1,...,d\}$. My question is: Given a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, how should I be interpreting expressions of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^d\sum_{j=1}^d V_i V_j f (y) \quad \mathbf{?}$$
Is $V_j$ acting as $(\dagger)$ on each component $f_k: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ separately? Can someone help me unfold this expression? For context these expressions show up at the beginning of Chapter 7 of the book Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths, by P. K. Friz & N. B. Victoir, where the authors explicitly write that the vector fields are to be seen as differential operators. So $V_i V_j f$ is not just a simple composition.

Is that construct $V: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^n)$ of a "matrix-valued" vector field from the authors? More conveniently (and in line with the standard literature) I would assume that every $V_i$ is of the form $(\dagger),.$ Then $V_iV_jf$ is a simple composition. Most parts of hat book are not visible in google. So you should provide more information.

Yes, the vector field $V$ appears in the context of controlled differential equations $dy_t = V(y_t) dx_t$ where $x:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are paths. My question derives from another question I posted. Namely, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5001993/step-n-euler-approximation-of-controlled-differential-equation . There I provide more context.
